# How is $-\sqrt{(x-1)^2} = -(x-1)$ false? (solved)

Tags: linear-algebra, algebra-precalculus

I got confused about Negative Square Roots after watching this videos on khanacademy and none of the comment helped. they all contradict each other. please skip to 4:20

https://www.khanacademy.org/math/algebra2/functions_and_graphs/function_inverses_2/v/function-inverses-example-3

based on my understanding of Square Roots and sal's explanation on previous videos, the following statement must be true:

$-\sqrt{(x-1)^2} = -(x-1)$

I don't understand how he gets:

$-\sqrt{(x-1)^2} = x-1$

The top comments try to justify this but I don't understand.

Comment: Notice that the left hand side is always negative, but the right hand side is not always negative.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

It depends on whether $x$ is less than or greater than $1$.

Generally, I interpret $-\sqrt{A}$ as meaning you take the positive square root of $A$ and then make it negative. So, 
$$-\sqrt{(x-1)^2}=-|x-1|=x-1 \ \text{ when } \ x<1$$ 
and 
$$-\sqrt{(x-1)^2}=-|x-1|=-(x-1) \ \text{ when } \ x>1.$$

Comment: Thank you, it helped me understand a little bit better, however how do I convert an absolute value statement to a polynomial? for example: $ -|x-1| = x - 1 \text{when}\ x < 1 $  Is there an easy  mechanical way?

Comment: @user4475969 Figure out when the thing inside the absolute value is positive and when it is negative. This is because $|A|=A$ if $A$ is positive and $|A|=-A$ when $A$ is negative (here $A$ can stand in for a more complicated algebraic expression, like $A=x-1$).

Comment: Absolute values can indeed be tricky! $|A|=A$ when $A>0$, and $|A|=-A$ when $A<0$. So $−|x−1|=x−1$ when $x-1>0$, therefore when $x>1$. And $−|x−1|=-(x−1)$ when $x-1<0$, therefore when $x<1$. This is the mechanics of it. An absolute value equation usually converts into 2 equations. Another example: $-|3-2x|=3-2x$ when $3-2x<0$, therefore when $3/2<x$. And $-|3-2x|=-(3-2x)$ when $3-2x>0$, therefore when $3/2>x$. Hope that helps!

Comment: @jdods it took me a while to understand it. but finally I do, thanks. However in the comment the equations for the first example are misplaced. I hope it's editable.

Comment: You are indeed correct! I did say they can be tricky! 

**Fix For Above Comment:**  
It should read: $−|x−1|=x−1$ when $x−1<0$, therefore when $x<1$. And $−|x−1|=−(x−1)$ when $x−1>0$, therefore when $x>1$.